# How to use the CancellationToken with Tasks.WaitAll()

Tags: .net, asynchronous, async-await, cancellation

I'm wondering how to use the `Task.WaitAll` overloads that take a `CancellationToken` as an argument, e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321573%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

The documentation says the `CancellationToken` argument is "A CancellationToken to observe while waiting for the tasks to complete."

Since `Task.WaitAll` is a blocking operation, how could you possibly "observe" it during that operation?  Furthermore, it says "The cancellationToken argument is used to cancel the wait operation. If it is canceled, the Wait returns false." but then it also says elsewhere that a `OperationCanceledException` is thrown when the `CancellationToken` is cancelled, meaning `Task.WaitAll` doesn't return `true` *or* `false`.

I'm either missing something really simple, or something is wrong with the documentation.  Either way, I'm thoroughly confused.  My ultimate goal is to be able to wait for multiple tasks to finish or to cancel them gracefully (via the proper use of `CancellationToken`) if they don't finish within a certain period of time.

This is related to my post [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/77710/wait-for-system-io-streamreader-readlineasync), but this time, I'm writing the async code and can observe the cancellation tokens.

Comment: `Task.WaitAll` is observing the token you pass to it.

Comment: @CodesInChaos -- so how is it ever cancelled then?  Who cancels it?

Comment: Note that cancelling `WaitAll` doesn't cancel the individual tasks. You need to also pass the token to the tasks, and depending on the nature of the task, they also need to explicitly check if the token has been cancelled.

Comment: "Who cancels it?" -- Whoever calls `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` on its source. For timeouts this happens through a timer created by the source.

Comment: @CodesInChaos -- "Whoever calls CancellationTokenSource.Cancel() on its source" -- Yes, I know that.  My understanding is that this mechanism is so that "main" threads can cancel "background" threads (tasks).  If the main thread is blocked on `Task.WaitAll`, then how can it call `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()`?

Comment: @roryap It is not that mainthread can cancel tasks. It could be any thread. To be precise whoever has a reference to `CancellationTokenSource` can cancel it. It is not necessarily main thread.

Comment: The timeout is triggered by a timer. For a `System.Threading.Timer` this code will run on a thread pool thread. The implementation of `CancellationTokenSource` probably does something like `if(timeOut != infinite) new Timer(timeOut, this.Cancel)`

Comment: "but then it also says elsewhere that a `OperationCanceledException` is thrown when the CancellationToken is cancelled" -- Link please. This could be a mistake in the documentation, or the statement was in a different context.

Comment: @CodesInChaos -- same link.

Comment: It throws the exception if the token has been canceled (even if that cancellation was due to a timeout). It only returns `false` if the timeout you pass to `WaitAll` expires before either token gets canceled or all tasks complete.

Comment: Why would you call `Task.WaitAll` in the first place, why not `Task.WhenAll` which returns an awaitable which can be awaited?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov -- Because the method I'm doing this in would then have to be an `async void` and it's the `Main` method of a command line application which doesn't allow `async`.

Comment: @roryap Right, i was hoping it wasn't :)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov and rory WhenAll doesn't require your method to be async. It returns a Task, you can wait on it again. As all the other methods declared async.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Since Task.WaitAll is a blocking operation, how could you possibly "observe" it during that operation?

You're not the one who observes it; it's the `Task.WaitAll` method that does.

> Furthermore, it says "The cancellationToken argument is used to cancel the wait operation. If it is canceled, the Wait returns false." but then it also says elsewhere that a OperationCanceledException is thrown when the CancellationToken is cancelled, meaning Task.WaitAll doesn't return true or false.

It seems to be a mistake in the documentation. It returns false if the specified timeout elapses before the tasks complete or the wait is canceled.

> Who cancels it?

Typically, some code running on another thread, since the current thread is already busy waiting for the tasks to complete. Or you could have called `CancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter` to specify a timeout after which the token is canceled.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot.  The one issue I have is that I've tested this by spawning a new thread that cancels the token, and instead of the `Task.WaitAll` returning false, an exception is thrown.  So is *that* the actual issue with the documentation?  It says it would return false, but it doesn't due to the exception.

Comment: @roryap, basically, yes. The doc is wrong, it's easily verifiable. I have already reported it with their feedback system, hopefully they'll fix it at some point.

Comment: It throws the exception if the token has been canceled (even if that cancellation was due to a timeout). It only returns false if the timeout you pass to WaitAll expires before either token gets canceled or all tasks complete.

Comment: @CodesInChaos -- "It only returns false if the timeout you pass to WaitAll expires before either token gets canceled or all tasks complete." -- then what timeout are you referring to in "It throws the exception if the token has been canceled (even if that cancellation was due to a **timeout**)"

Comment: @roryap You can (optionally) pass a timeout the the `CancellationTokenSource` and a separate timeout to `WaitAll`. The former results in an exception, the latter in `false`.